# Module related issue - calendar module

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Whenever I try to print a calendar using module cmd is showing an error

> File "C:\Users\imposter\Desktop\pyf\eg1.py", line 1, in 
> import calendar   File "C:\Users\imposter\Desktop\pyf\calendar.py", line 14, in 
> print(calendar.month(yy, mm)) AttributeError: partially initialized module 'calendar' has no attribute 'month' (most likely
> due to a circular import)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: do you have a program name called `calendar.py` in `C:\Users\imposter\Desktop\pyf\calendar.py` ? If so, you may have to rename that program before you run it. I think this program is trying to import that python file.

Answer (score 0):

you properly copy this code and try to run

```
import calendar  
    
yy = 2017
mm = 11
    
# display the calendar  
print(calendar.month(yy, mm))
```

Output:

```
November 2017
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
       1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30
```

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because you have a file named `calendar.py` in your project which is shadowing the `calendar` module from Python's standard library. Rename that file and the issue should go away.